# What does $H X H^T$ do?

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

I regularly encounter the use of:

$$H X H^T$$

Where:

- $H$ is a $(n\times m)$ matrix, with $H^T$ it's transpose
- $X$ is a $(m \times m)$ matrix

If we rephrased this as a function (unquely defined for each H:
$$f_H(X): \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}  \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} : X \mapsto H X H^T$$

then what does the function $f_H$ do? Does it make sense to think of it that way?

Notionally what is this operation?
I feel like there must be some intuitive notion of what it is doing.

It shows up (for example) in the [Kalman Filter equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter): $ \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} = \mathbf{F}_{k} \mathbf{P}_{k-1\mid k-1} \mathbf{F}_{k}^{\text{T}} + \mathbf{Q}_{k}$.

Is seems like I am performing a operation which includes moving to some different space, and then performing the other half of the operation while moving back again.

Comment: What are you looking for? Would you like to encounter special properties of such matrices? to this end, notice that for $m<n$, every $n\times m$ matrix can be written in that form, due to SVD.

Comment: @DimitarM.H. Editted to clarify. 
I am looking at this as if each $H$ described some particular function $f_H$. I am not certain if that is a good way to think about it. My feeling is "H is doing *something* to X"

Comment: @oxinabox Rahul's answer is correct. You can think of the congruence transform (not to be confused with similarity transform) as a quadratic form under coordinate change (if $H$ is a square matrix). Another situation is when $H$ is some Jacobian matrix and $X$ is a Riemannian metric, then the "pull-back" of the metric is in the form of $H^TXH$ (rather than $HXH^T$). In this sense, you can say it is moving to some space, then performing an operation and then move back.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to change the notation slightly by setting $A=X$ and $B=H^T$.

$B^TAB$ represents the change of basis of a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms). If $B$ is invertible, then the matrices $A$ and $B^TAB$ are [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence).

More explicitly, if $A$ represents a quadratic form on $y\in\mathbb R^n$,
$$f(y) = y^TAy,$$
but $y$ itself depends linearly on $x\in\mathbb R^m$,
$$y = g(x) = Bx,$$
then the [corresponding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback) quadratic form on $x$ is represented by $B^TAB$:
$$f(g(x)) = (Bx)^TA(Bx) = x^T(B^TAB)x.$$

Comment: I've not seen quadratic forms before, I'm struggling a bit to see how $H$ and $y$ are connected. Is it possible to clarify that in the introduction to your answer? (Or would that be far too long, and i should go off and do some reading.)